# Botón que coja la posición de la siguiente palabra y la resalte

Tags: c#, botón, click

Tengo un botón que busca la palabra que yo quiera en un TextBox y me la resalta. Lo que necesito es un botón ("siguiente") que al hacer click resalte la siguiente palabra que coincida con la palabra que he buscado y coja su posición. Mi botón es asi:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)          
{  
    new mailSpam().ResaltarTexto((TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"], textBox3.Text);
}
```

Esto esta en otra clase:

```
public void ResaltarTexto(TextBox txtBx, string texto)
{
    int posición = txtBx.Text.IndexOf(texto);

    txtBx.Focus();
    txtBx.SelectionStart = posición;
    txtBx.SelectionLength = texto.Length;
}
```

Había pensado en algo así pero me salta un error "No se controlo NullReferenceException" y no me hace nada, y lo que quiero conseguir es que me resalte la siguiente palabra que coincida con la palabra que ya ha buscado.:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    indicePalabra++;

    if (indicePalabra > listaPalabras.Length-1)
    {
        indicePalabra=0;
    }

    try
    {
        textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(listaPalabras[indicePalabra]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

El textBox 1 es el que contiene el texto donde se resaltan y buscan las palabras y luego tengo otro textBox en el que escribo la  palabra que quiero buscar.

Comment: Hola Guille. "no consigo hacerlo de la manera correcta" .. puedes elaborar más la explicacion? Por qué no funciona? Pon ejemplos de los datos introducidos, del resultado esperado y el que actualemente estás obteniendo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: Me salta el error "no se controlo nulReferenceException" en la linea del length-1 y no me hace nada y lo que quiero conseguir es que me resalte la siguiente palabra que coincida con la palabra que ya ha buscado.

Comment: Añade esa informacion y la que te pido (los ejemplos) a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo un botón que te devuelve la posición de una palabra, si lo que quieres hacer es encontrar la siguiente posición, sólo tendrías que buscar a partir de la primera aparición.

El código del botón siguiente sería:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)          
{  
    new mailSpam().ResaltarTexto((TextBox)this.Controls["textBox1"], textBox3.Text.Substring(pos_primera_aparicion, textBox3.Text.Length-1));
}
```

siendo posición la posición de la última letra de la palabra que has buscado.

Comment: Y como le paso la posicion desde la otra classe? O creo una nueva variable posicion para trabajar con ella directamente en el boton?

Comment: yo me guardaría la posición en una variable, es lo más sencillo

Comment: lo has probado?

Comment: perdona la tardanza, he estado fuera. estoy poniendo la variable (posicion) en la que guardo la posicion de la busqueda como primera aparicion pero no se como pasarsela al boton desde la funcion de la otra clase

Comment: Si no lo entiendo mal, tu tienes el TextBox y el botón en una clase(formulario) y la función para buscar las palabras está en otra clase? Si es así no se porque lo haces así, pero si es así, igual que devuelves la posición de la palabra a la primera clase, devuelve la posición y cuando pulses el botón envíala también

Comment: Vale ya lo he conseguido muchas gracias :)